# Date-picker sometimes is stuck and I have no error Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs-datepicker

I use [vue-date-pick](https://dbrekalo.github.io/vue-date-pick/getting-started.html) . The problem is that sometimes the date picker is stuck. Ex:(1. select date, (show in input)-> select date, (show in input), select date (**don't change in input**)), and the problem is that is random ,and no error message. If is a problem with this date-pick, I can change to another (but must have a display-format option. Just for DOM)

```
<date-pick
    v-model="setDate"
></date-pick>

import DatePick from 'vue-date-pick';

data(){
   return{
     setDate:'',
   }
}
```

Comment: Try [vuejs-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker)

Comment: From what I saw It doesn't have display format option. And format from server is YYYY-MM-DD, so I will have error on post,if format is changed..

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker#date-formatting)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it with the solution from [here](https://github.com/dbrekalo/vue-date-pick/issues/28).

The problem is if you use vue-bootstrap.

You have to edit the module. (src/dist folders)

Remove `focusin` from:

```
['click', 'keyup', 'focusin'].forEach( eventName => document.addEventListener(eventName, this.closeEventListener) );
```